# ArcPy with ArcMap cannot delete file

Tags: arcpy, delete, lock, error-000601

I have a Python tool to calculate some simple statistics on a lot of features. I use `arcpy.Statistics_analysis` to create a DBF file with stats for a feature class, register the results, then pass to the following.
So I would like to use a temporary file for each feature class, then delete it before passing to the next.
Unfortunately this temporary file seems impossible to delete, also if I use `arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True`

Any hint ?

here is my code

```
for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_type='polygon'):

    if arcpy.Exists(outFolder + os.sep + "appo.dbf"):
        arcpy.Delete_management(outFolder + os.sep + "appo.dbf")

    arcpy.Statistics_analysis(fc, outFolder + os.sep + "appo.dbf", [["Ettari", "SUM"]])
```

the error message is

> ExecuteError: ERROR 000601: Cannot delete
> C:\Terna\Connessioni\appo\appo.dbf.  May be locked by another
> application.
>
> Failed to execute (Delete)

Comment: What do you mean by "register the results"? Locks are created on active tables. If it's still active, you shouldn't be able to delete it.

Comment: I mean that i write numbers I get into a database. The temporary table is no more affected by my tool

Comment: Where/how are you running this code?  In the interactive Python window in Pro, in a Jupyter notebook in Pro, in a stand-alone Python session outside of Pro, etc...

Comment: my toolbox in ArcGis Desktop 10.3.1

Comment: Does the code work on the first iteration through the loop and then fail after?

Comment: yes, exactly this way. My partial solution is to create files wih different names at each iteration, and delete them all together at the. But also in this way, the last one cannot be deleted until ArcMap is closed ... So boring ....

Answer (score -3):

[Unlocker](https://unlocker.en.softonic.com/) is a great freeware utility that can delete application-locked files.